# Maestro testing framework does not recognize InkWell in a Card in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, maestro

In my Flutter project, I'm currently testing [Maestro](https://maestro.mobile.dev/) for my end-to-end tests.

It works well, but I just came across a weird bug (as explained [here](https://github.com/mobile-dev-inc/maestro/issues/1691)).

Let's say I create a `Card`, with an `InkWell` in it, as detailed below:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Card(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Introduction text"),
            SizedBox(height: 24),
            Material(
              type: MaterialType.transparency,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () => print("PRESSED"),
                child: Text("PRESS"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now, if I test it with Maestro, it does not see the `PRESS` button (I even tried it with Maestro Studio). It only sees the whole card as a single component, as if everything was flattened.

But as soon as I add another clickable widget in the card, Maestro works as expected and sees every clickable element in the card.

So the first workaround I could obviously think of is to add an invisible clickable widget in every card in that situation, but:

- I would need to do that in multiple parts of my app
- it's very ugly

So my question is: is there a better/cleaner workaround that I could implement so Maestro works in my use case, without changing any design aspect of my page?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no experience with Maestro at all but I wonder if the `type: MaterialType.transparency,` could have something to do with it. What if you leave that line out and then maybe use `color: Colors.transparent,` instead? Or see if the test succeeds when you leave out that `Material` completely?

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried it and it still not working. Good point, though!

Answer (score 2):

After a deep dive into the Flutter SDK, especially the `TextButton` source code, I finally found a clean way to solve my problem by using the `Semantics` widget with a specific argument as described below:

```
Semantics(
  container: true,
  child: Material(
    type: MaterialType.transparency,
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () => print("PRESSED"),
      child: Text("PRESS"),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Now, Maestro recognizes the `InkWell` widget as expected.